# Install4j hide Error Messages

Tags: install4j

I have a Problem with the Install4j Startup Error Message:

When I start my app, a splash screen appears. 
During this i try to establish a database connection. 
if that fails, the app quits with an error message. 
at the same time, an error message from install4j pops up.

[image: Startup Error]

Where do I set that the install4j error message is not displayed?

thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the launcher wizard, on the "Executable info" step, deselect the "Fail if an exception in the main thread is thrown" check box.

[image]